# Questions for python->scheme conversion

Tags: python, arrays, scheme

I currently am trying to write a Python program using scheme semantics so I can later translate it into Scheme without relying on a lot of Pythonic stuff.

I'm trying solve the sliding puzzle problem (where you have 9 slots and 8 tiles arranged in a square) using a*, depth first, and breadth first search algorithm.  I did this ~11 years ago in some AI class in Lisp, but basically at the time I had no idea about lisp, I hated it with all my heart, and only in retrospect do I realize I was programming "C" in Lisp.  The prof didn't help in this matter.

I have a python function which can swap two tiles easily:

```
def swap(p, (r1, c1), (r2, c2)):  
    # Swaps *any* two locations and returns new configuration  
    # Does not concern itself with zero location, etc  
    # Not sure how to do this functionally  
    p_p = p[:]  
    temp = p_p[r1][c1]  
    p_p[r1][c1] = p_p[r2][c2]  
    p_p[r2][c2] = temp  
    return p_p
```

I'd like to turn this into something you might find in SICP, avoiding side effects, etc.

But this brings up a question.  Everything I read in SICP is loops via recursion.  I didn't see anything in accessing arrays/vectors/lists in constant time.  I can imagine a loopish/recursive way to read an element, but I find it harder to imagine a way to create a new list with a certain element changed, without invoking side-effect producing things like set!, and without resorting to crazy if/then/else clauses concerning which element should be changed.  This of course gets more confusing when considering a 2d array.  In this case the solution with python is obvious because of its native support for multidimensional arrays.

In C/C++/Python/Matlab/Lua/anything else, accessing lists/arrays via the [i] syntax is easy, and directly translates to a hardware-oriented pointer lookup somewhere underneath.  I don't understand how scheme does this, given the atomic operations defined in the SICP version of scheme, which all seem very loop-and-search oriented.  How do the vector and list array access functions work to get constant time access?  (I'm a total newbie here, so I'm not ever sure what functions I'd be talking about).  Is there a C or Assembly library someplace which is secretly being accessed?  Are there any inherent constant-time semantics in scheme which could be used for list/array/vector access, and which would allow me a guilt-free way of using that idiom in Python for the moment?

How would can I rewrite the above function in python using Schemish semantics?  How would I rewrite the above function in Scheme?

Comment: Start small: ask the question: how get n-th element in Scheme in constant time i.e., O(1)? possible answer: use vectors (make-vector dimension element). Next: are there multidimensinal arrays in scheme? possible answer: for 2d there is a matrix, for > 2d easily constructed from 1d vector, etc ...

Comment: Note that what you're doing in your Python code isn't correct either. You do `p_p = p[:]` presumably to not affect the original contents of `p` (otherwise why not just manipulate `p` directly?). However, that only copies the top level. You are assigning into elements at the second level, so those changes will still affect the 2D array as seen from `p`. However, the end result is that `p` will neither the same as the pre-swap `p` (unless `c1` and `c2` happen to be the same), nor the same as the result of `swap`. It will be some horrible intermediate mix.

Answer (score 4):

You identified that your initial problem was trying to write C semantics in Lisp. Is it not repeating the mistake to try to write scheme semantics in python? I always try to learn language X as a paradigm as much as a language and write in the most x-ish way.

It might be justifiable if this was a business app you knew was going to be migrated, but otherwise I'd just write it in scheme to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an 8-puzzle solver in Lisp about a year ago. I just used a list of 3 lists, each sublist with 3 elements being the numbers. It's not constant time, but it is portable.

Anyways, if you are really interested in doing this functionally (Scheme doesn't require you to) what is easiest to do is to create some helper functions that will get a specific value given row/col and 'set' a value given row/col. Instead of modifying the original data structure, the set operation will construct the new state based on the old state.

Then you can write a swap operation based on these get and set operations. Here's what I wrote about a year ago in Common Lisp, but it's easily convertible to Scheme:

```
; getval
;
; This function takes a position (r . c) where and returns the corresponding
; number in the 8-puzzle state. For example, if you wanted (1 . 2) from
; ((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)), the value would be 6. The r and c values begin
; at 0.
;
; parameters:  pos    The position to get
;              state  The 8-puzzle state
; returns:     The value at pos in state
(defun getval (pos state)
  (if (null state) 'no-value
      (if (= 0 (car pos))
      (if (= 0 (cdr pos))
          (caar state)
          (getval (cons (car pos) (- (cdr pos) 1)) (list (cdar state))))
      (getval (cons (- (car pos) 1) (cdr pos)) (cdr state)))))

; setval
;
; This function returns a state where the value at pos is replaced by val.
; Like getval, this function is zero-based. Accessing beyond the size of
; the state is undefined (and probably broken)
;
; parameters:  pos    Position to set
;              val    Value to set
;              state  State to modify
; returns:     New state where pos is val
(defun setval (pos val state)
  (if (null state) '()
      (if (= 0 (car pos))
      (if (= 0 (cdr pos))
          (cons (cons val (cdar state)) (cdr state))
          (let ((temp (setval (cons (car pos) (- (cdr pos) 1)) val
                  (cons (cdar state) (cdr state)))))
        (cons (cons (caar state) (car temp)) (cdr temp))))
      (cons (car state) (setval (cons (- (car pos) 1) (cdr pos)) val (cdr state))))))

; state-swap
;
; This function takes a state and two positions and returns a new state with
; the values in those two positions swapped.
;
; parameters:  state  State to swap within
;              a      Position to swap with b
;              b      Position to swap with a
; return:      State with a swapped with b
(defun state-swap (state a b)
  (let ((olda (getval a state)) (oldb (getval b state)))
    (setval a oldb (setval b olda state))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to achieve it.  Recreate the list using a function which will apply the appropriate mapping.

```
def swap(p, (r1,c1), (r2,c2)):
    def getitem(r,c):
        if (r,c) == (r1,c1): return p[r2][c2]
        elif (r,c) == (r2,c2): return p[r1][c1]
        return p[r][c]
    return [ [getitem(r,c) for c in range(len(p[0]))] for r in range(len(p)) ]
```

You could even take this a step further and make the function be the actual interface, where each swap merely returns a function that does the appropriate conversions before passing through to the function below.  Not particularly performant, but a fairly simple functional approach that dispenses with nasty mutable datastructures:

```
def swap(f, (r1,c1), (r2,c2)):
    def getitem(r,c):
        if (r,c) == (r1,c1): return f(r2,c2)
        elif (r,c) == (r2,c2): return f(r1,c1)
        return f(r,c)
   return getitem

l=[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,0]]
f=lambda r,c: l[r][c]    # Initial accessor function
f=swap(f, (2,1), (2,2))  # 8 right
f=swap(f, (1,1), (2,1))  # 5 down
print [[f(x,y) for y in range(3)] for x in range(3)]
# Gives: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 0, 6], [7, 5, 8]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I like this approach.  It's exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

Cool, thanks for the lisp code.  I'll need to study it to make sure I get it.

As for the first answer, the first time I was "writing c" in lisp because that's the only way I knew how to program and didn't have a clue why anyone would use lisp.  This time around, I've been playing around with scheme, but wanted to use python so if I got stuck on something I could "cheat" and use something pythonish, then while waiting for usenet answers go on to the next part of the problem.